# Run code in Vaadin 8 application idependent of UI

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

In earlier versions, you could have a class which implements ServletContextListener and put your code in the contextInitialized method, so that  it runs when the server starts. This is useful for loading up the database into memory. How does one achieve this in a Vaadin 8 project?

Comment: What's you set up? Spring? Or plain web application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In exactly the same way: By registering a `ServletContextListener`. You can use the `@WebListener` annotation for this. For example:

```
public class WebConfig {

    @WebServlet("/*")
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = VaadinUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class JdbcExampleVaadinServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @WebListener
    public static class JdbcExampleContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            try {
                DatabaseService.init();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            DatabaseService.shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please note that when using Spring Boot, you might also have to use the `@ServletComponentScan ` annotation on your application to actually make it pick up classes annotated with e.g. `@WebListener`.

Comment: I was missing the annotation. Thanks, Alejandro!