# Vaadin 8: Where to store file created at server start in ServletContextListener

Tags: vaadin8, servletcontextlistener

I want to create a file with data from the database only once at server start and store the file.

I found the helpful examples:[ServletContextListener Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588743/hook-for-my-vaadin-web-app-starting-and-stopping) and [ServletContextListener Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531773/run-code-in-vaadin-8-application-idependent-of-ui).

I wanted to store my file created in the contextInitialized method in the following directory:

```
String fileName = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/WEB-INF/fileName.xlsx";
```

But I get a Nullpointer exception for VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

It seems not be available at start.

Where can I store my file so that a user can download it later?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: VaadinService.getCurrent() will return null if it is not being called from main thread, that could be one reason.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if the ServletContextListener code is executed in a different thread? Is there any other directory I could store my file without having to call VaadinService.getCurrent()?

Comment: How the application is been deployed?

Comment: I am using Maven 3, Tomcat 9 and a Postgres database.

Comment: I have implemented a workaround. I store the file created in the ServletContextListener in the System tmp folder. Then in Ui init I copy the file to the WEB-INF folder. However, I would prefer to store the file directly in the WEB-INF folder if possible.